# Cycle though all the instances of a currently active application in all workspaces

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, workspaces, workspace-switcher

When we press <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd>, then we cycle through ALL the applications instances in CURRENT workspace.

When we press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Tab</kbd>, then we cycle through ALL the applications instances in ALL the workspaces.

When we press <kbd>Alt+` (backtick)</kbd>, then we cycle though ALL the instances of currently active application in **current** workspace.

---

==> Now, I want to know some way or some extension, so that with some keyboard stroke, can i cycle through ALL the instances of currently active application in **all** workspaces.

Hence, for example, that is,in Unity DE, if currently active application is "gedit"(say), Then is there an extension or a way, so that by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+`(backtick)</kbd> (say), we can cycle through all the instances of gedit only in any workspace ?

Answer (score 0):

Starting in I believe 16.04 it's an option, not sure of the current default as I've changed here to make a single hand binding (Ctrl+Alt+z)

You should find in ccsm, (install compizconfig-settings-manager) > Ubuntu Unity Plugin as in screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying. I followed all the steps as detailed in your answer, BUT still it didnot worked for me :'-(